# Python 3.4 crashes when opening an image with PIL in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, osx-lion, python-imaging-library

I have no idea why but even for the simplest of scripts python crashes and I get the following message:

> "ActivePython 3.4 quit unexpectedly."

I'm running it on a `Mac, OSX 10.7.5`.

The code I'm running to test it is:

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

root = Tk()

image = Image.open("/Users/Name/Desktop/image.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image_label = Label(root, width = 400, height = 400, image = photo)

root.mainloop()
```

I think it's a problem with tkinter rather than PIL because the following code works fine:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

image = Image.open("/Users/Name/Desktop/image.png")
image.show()
```

Any guesses at why this could be?

I thought I'd post a section of the error log, despite how long it is, in the hope it somehow helps resolve this frustrating problem.

```
Process:         Python [377]
Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         3.4.1 (3.4.1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  Python [286]

Date/Time:       2015-05-26 19:43:38.689 +1000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          17865335 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           138
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  152 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   18
Anonymous UUID:                      7F4893CF-A95E-4ED6-85E7-2B6A5A32AC0C

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000050

VM Regions Near 0x50:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
objc[377]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   Tk                              0x0000000105332fb6 Tk_GetImageMasterData + 18
1   Tk                              0x0000000105340fbf Tk_FindPhoto + 17
2   _imagingtk.so                   0x000000010305caec PyImagingPhotoPut + 92
3   Tcl                             0x00000001051df261 TclInvokeStringCommand + 121
4   Tcl                             0x00000001010714b1 TclEvalObjvInternal + 782
5   Tcl                             0x00000001010726a3 Tcl_EvalObjv + 66
6   _tkinter.so                     0x00000001007f1ace Tkapp_Call + 190
7   org.python.python               0x00000001000e542b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 31291
8   org.python.python               0x00000001000e665d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
9   org.python.python               0x00000001000e51f7 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 30727
10  org.python.python               0x00000001000e665d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
11  org.python.python               0x000000010003f76a function_call + 186
12  **org.python.python                 0x000000010000da08 PyObject_Call + 104
13  org.python.python               0x000000010002941c method_call + 140
14  org.python.python               0x000000010000da08 PyObject_Call + 104
15  org.python.python               0x0000000100078651 slot_tp_init + 81
16  org.python.python               0x00000001000736c4 type_call + 212
17  org.python.python               0x000000010000da08 PyObject_Call + 104
18  org.python.python               0x00000001000e1c3f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16975
19  org.python.python               0x00000001000e665d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
20  org.python.python               0x00000001000e671f PyEval_EvalCode + 63
21  org.python.python               0x00000001000dae3e builtin_exec + 206
22  org.python.python               0x00000001000e542b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 31291
23  org.python.python               0x00000001000e665d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
24  org.python.python               0x000000010003f76a function_call + 186
25  org.python.python               0x000000010000da08 PyObject_Call + 104
26  org.python.python               0x00000001000e0ffe PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13838
27  org.python.python               0x00000001000e665d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
28  org.python.python               0x00000001000e51f7 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 30727
29  org.python.python               0x00000001000e665d PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
30  org.python.python               0x00000001000e671f PyEval_EvalCode + 63
31  org.python.python               0x00000001001111e7 PyRun_StringFlags + 183
32  org.python.python               0x0000000100111271 PyRun_SimpleStringFlags + 65
33  org.python.python               0x0000000100127e55 Py_Main + 1445
34  org.python.python               0x0000000100000e32 0x100000000 + 3634
35  org.python.python               0x0000000100000c84 0x100000000 + 3204**
```

Comment: Is that all error output you get? Also, does the same code work in Python 2.7?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, that's the only error I get. I can't run it in Python 2.7 as I don't have the correct tkinter and PIL modules installed. If I install them for 2.7 could it create more mess?

Comment: I do get a crash report, but it's many many lines long. The only bit that looks interesting to me (maybe) is:

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000050

Comment: I entered: $ sudo pip3 install Pillow, and received: $ Requirement already satisfied.

Comment: @SGB Try to report the error here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues, they might be able to help fast. If you discover the solution, please share it with us here on Stack Overflow as an answer!

Comment: Update: I uninstalled all versions of python and re-installed python 3.4.1. Installed all modules except ActivePython; however it's still crashing with:
"Python quit unexpectedly."

Comment: @SGB Have you tried to open an _issue_ on the github repository I mentioned above or not?

Comment: Hi Xenomorph, yes I have now. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1241 I've pretty much just copied and pasted from my post here.

Comment: Possibly it doesn't like that you don't grid() or pack() the label???

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's not it. Seems Pillow and tkinter just don't play well, (at least on my machine). It's obviously not common as googling this issue gives me practically no hits (except my own).

Answer (score 0):

I posted my question over at github and user 'radarhere' pointed me to the solution.

Tk extension libraries will sometimes link against /System/Library/Frameworks instead of /Library/Frameworks. There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but I simply renamed the Tcl.frameworks and TK.frameworks folders in the path System/Library/Frameworks and voila! No python crash and the image displayed as expected.